# Extjs Intermittent error

Tags: javascript, extjs, rendering, extjs4.1

Using Extjs 4.1, an intermittent error is occurring.
Sometimes it occurs, but most of the time it does not.
It always occurs when I start the application, so I press F5 and everything returns to normal.

Using [this reference](https://github.com/AlexandreN84/extjs_4.1/blob/master/ext-all-debug-w-comments.js) to debug the error, I noticed that it occurs at line 29590.

The error message is very generic:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null
>       at constructor.finishRender (ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:29590)
>       at constructor.finishRenderItems (ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:39796)
>       at constructor.finishRender (ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:40889)
>       at constructor.finishRenderChildren (ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:44526)
>       at constructor.afterRender (ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:29331)
>       at constructor.callParent (ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:6194)
>       at constructor.afterRender (ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:36521)
>       at constructor.finishRender (ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:29625)
>       at constructor.finishRenderItems (ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:39796)
>       at constructor.finishRender (ext-all-debug-w-comments.js:40889)

[Here is an error print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnqfK.png)

What must be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I would have made this a comment, but it doesn't fit.

There is a wide variety of reasons I could think of. Most of them are based on asynchronous calls. You definitely have to provide more information for the question to be answerable.

Obviously, `me.el` is null, which it shouldn't be. So first you have to find which component is causing the problem. For this, you should exchange line 29590 against something like this:

```
try {
    me.container = Ext.get(me.el.dom.parentNode);
} catch(e) {
    console.log(me.id);
    console.log(me.itemId);
    console.log(me.xtype);
    ...
    console.log(me);
    throw e;
}
```

This should give you an idea which component(s) would be affected.

Then show us the code of that component. Also check whether you modify that component's config from outside the component, e.g. from a store load operation or other asynchronous tasks. Plus you should look at whether overrides for the component and its ancestors are loaded from separate JS files - maybe they are sometimes loaded before, sometimes after the finishRender has been called, and fix exactly this error.

These are only a few of the possible reasons.

Comment: Grateful for the return. I added the `try catch` as you mentioned. But the error is no longer occurring. As soon as I get a return I comment here.